# Inform invalid session if other user in other tab

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jsp, jquery

I have something to resolve. I have a website use Spring security for authentication and check login ...When user open two tab, a one tab they login with one user account, and other tab, user will login with other user account. I want to inform to a first tab that "you're invalid session" or "have other user account login" or something like that. It's like how gmail works.

Now, I have some idea:

1. I will use ajax to check with server every 5s and get the information of current user account.
2. Trap before click event and ajaxSend event for check with server, if have other user account, abort it and inform to user.
3. Use WebSocket for communicate with server. I think server need to manage a lot of user account and it will make server work a lot.

Any idea about that?

Thanks in advance!